# JavaScript Date Duration Calculation

Tags: javascript, date, duration

I thought I had written code to calculate the duration between two given dates.

However I'm getting an incorrect calculation for the example below.

The example below is counting an extra year...

Kindly help please....

```
var fromdate = "03/10".split("/");
var todate = "01/14".split("/");
var months = todate[0] - fromdate[0] + 12 * (todate[1] - fromdate[1]);
var duration = Math.round(months / 12) + " years " + (months % 12) + " months";
console.log(duration)
```

Comment: You should just make two date objects from those strings and subtract them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use floor instead of round:

```
var duration = Math.round(months / 12) + " years " + (months % 12) + " months";
                   ^---// Change to Math.floor
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
var start = Date.now();

console.log('Start', start);

setTimeout(function() {
  var end = Date.now();
  var elapsed = end - start; // elapsed time in milliseconds

  console.log('End', end);
  console.log('Duration', elapsed)
  }, 1234
);
```